# How to use Poco library in a simple C++ project?

Tags: c++, cmake, poco-libraries

This is my project's directory structure:

```
poco/
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
```

note: poco directory contains all the file downloaded from Poco's github repository by using this command:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/pocoproject/poco.git
```

This is the content of the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_executable(
    main
    main.cpp
)
add_subdirectory(poco)
include_directories(
   poco/ApacheConnector/include
   poco/CppParser/include
   poco/CppUnit/include
   poco/Crypto/include
   poco/Data/include
   poco/Encodings/include
   poco/Foundation/include
   poco/JSON/include
   poco/MongoDB/include
   poco/Net/include
   poco/NetSSL_OpenSSL/include
   poco/NetSSL_Win/include
   poco/openssl/build/include
   poco/PDF/include
   poco/Redis/include
   poco/SevenZip/include
   poco/Util/include
   poco/XML/include
   poco/Zip/include
)

target_link_libraries(main ${POCO_LIBRARIES})
```

And this is the content of the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::cout << "here";

    return 0;
}
```

After I run these commands(in the directory whose structure was presented):

```
$mkdir _build && cd _build
$cmake ..
$make
```

I encounter these errors:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
[  1%] Linking CXX executable main
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::host() const':
/home/gandalf/Desktop/pocoTest/poco/Net/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:143: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPAddress(void const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::~IPv6SocketAddressImpl()':
/home/gandalf/Desktop/pocoTest/poco/Net/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:118: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::~IPv6SocketAddressImpl()':
/home/gandalf/Desktop/pocoTest/poco/Net/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:118: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::~IPv4SocketAddressImpl()':
/home/gandalf/Desktop/pocoTest/poco/Net/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:56: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::~IPv4SocketAddressImpl()':
/home/gandalf/Desktop/pocoTest/poco/Net/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:56: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::host() const':
/home/gandalf/Desktop/pocoTest/poco/Net/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:81: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPAddress(void const*, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE[_ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE[_ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE[_ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE[_ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'main' failed
make[2]: *** [main] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

From what I have figured out, `Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPAddress` must be `Poco::Net::IPAddress`. And I don't know why the linker adds an extra `IPAddress` to `Poco::Net::IPAddress`. 
And this problem seems to arise from an error in CMakeLists.txt
So how can I fix this?

Comment: `POCO_LIBRARIES` is unset, so you're not linking against the library.

Comment: @JohnZwinck What should I do instead?

Comment: The linker adds another `IPAddress` because it refers to the constructor of that class. Just wondering: Can't you find packages that provide Poco so you don't need to manually install them?

Comment: I tried find_package but I got this error:

Comment: By not providing "FindPoco.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Poco"

Comment: @gandalf `find_package` only work with compiled and installed package. It can be installed in a custom directory though, and that directory can be in your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `target_link_libraries(main ${POCO_LIBRARIES})` won't work as intended. That variable is only defined in find modules. It may not even work with modern packages.

If you want to use poco as a project subdirectory, then I suggest to link to their targets:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_executable(
    main
    main.cpp
)

add_subdirectory(poco)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC PocoNet ...) # replace `...` by all poco library you use
```

Comment: I tried this but got the following error while running make command in _build directory:
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>

Comment: @gandalf try with `PocoNet` instead

Comment: sorry my bad, I forgot to add this line add_subdirectory(poco)

Comment: After running make I got this error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoPUBLIC

Comment: @gandalf there is no poco library named `PUBLIC`. That all caps argument is the visibility of the dependency in CMake. It should be : `target_link_libraries(your_target <PUBLIC|PRIVATE|INTERFACE> all_your_dependencies_here)`

Comment: @gandalf read the documentation, I used the syntax here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#libraries-for-a-target-and-or-its-dependents

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, As you said I added the following, in place of `...`:
 `PocoData
        PocoDataSQLite
        PocoEncodings
        PocoFoundation
        PocoJSON
        PocoMongoDB
        PocoNet
        PocoRedis
        PocoUtil
        PocoXML
        PocoZip`
And it was built fine and there seems to be no problem

Comment: Is `main` the name of your project?

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm no, only the name of the executable. You can have many executable and libraries per projects.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question. I did build the following testcase. It is based on a Linux System (opensuse). This example is not perfect -- no guarantee.

`bash` commands:

```sh
$ git clone --depth=1 --branch=master --recurse-submodules https://github.com/pocoproject/poco.git
$ cd poco && mkdir poco-build && cd poco-build
$ cmake -H .. -B . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/libs
$ cmake --build . --target install
```

The bash routines will compile the poco library and installs the needed headers/libraries/cmake/... files locally in `~/libs`. Of course this can be changed.

---

Using the following files.

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(PocoTimer)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/<user>/libs/poco/lib/cmake/Poco)

find_package(Poco REQUIRED Foundation)

add_executable(
    main main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
    main
    PRIVATE Poco::Foundation
)
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include "Poco/Timer.h"
#include "Poco/Thread.h"
#include "Poco/Stopwatch.h"
#include <iostream>

/*
 * Main application 
 */

class PocoTimer
{
public:
    //------------
    PocoTimer() { stopWatch.start(); }
    //------------
    void PrintElapsedTime(Poco::Timer& timer)
    {
      std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << stopWatch.elapsed() / 1000 << " milliseconds." << std::endl;
    }
private:
    Poco::Stopwatch stopWatch;
};


int main() {

PocoTimer pocoTimer;
Poco::Timer timer(250, 500);
// -- print command -- //
timer.start(Poco::TimerCallback<PocoTimer>(pocoTimer, &PocoTimer::PrintElapsedTime));
Poco::Thread::sleep(5000);
timer.stop();

}
```

---

Alternative you can use `cmake` flags instead of `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ...)` in the `CMakeLists.txt`. This makes it more flexible if you want to use different Poco instances.

Example if you 'installed' Poco to `~/libs`:

```
$ cmake -H. -B./build \
      -DPoco_DIR='/home/<user>/libs/poco/lib/cmake/Poco'
```

or

```
$ cmake -H. -B./build \
      -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH='/home/<user>/libs/poco/lib/cmake/Poco'
```

or

```
$ cmake -H. -B./build \
      -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH='/home/<user>/libs/poco/lib/cmake/Poco'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard way of using cmake but it works

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
    project(view)
    set(SOURCE ./src/main.cc)#add your additional source file here!
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
    set(POCO_LIB_PATH /home/soloknight/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-linux/lib)
    include_directories(/home/soloknight/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-linux/include)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE})
    install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
    target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${POCO_LIB_PATH})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PocoFoundation)
```

I'm using vcpkg to download stuff then linking it to my test project and it's working
you have to just set POCO_LIB_PATH and include
NOTE : I'm using linux so if you are on windows system  maybe you will need extra path setting